# Get Mosek License's usage stats

Tags: mosek

We have purchased multiple Mosek Floating Licenses

We want to get Mosek License's usage information (i.e. which employee was using the license at what point of time). Something like this:

[image: example]

Although, there's seems to be a low level log file [lmgrd.log](https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/licensing/floating-license.html#linux-token-server-setup) (which logs every license request), but this requires implementing a parser layer to extract info.

We have the following questions:

- Does Mosek give any out of the box utility (preferably through its CVXPY API) to get this license usage information?
- If not, what is the best way to achieve this in Mosek?
- Finally, if extracting info from lmgrd.log is the only option - then what is the structure / format of that lmgrd.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOSEK has no utility, especially not through CVXPY. The MOSEK distribution includes a set of administrative tools such as lmtools, lmutil and so on from Flexera, which can be used to obtain various information. The most comprehensive guide to those is the FlexNet License Administration Guide which is linked just at the beginning of https://www.mosek.com/documentation/ That guide is the best place to start.